# Test Framework quit unexpectedly Error - Cucumber Java IntelliJ

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I am strugling to run a simple Cucumber script in IntelliJ. After resolving all dependancy issue now when i run scenario I am getting error as :
Test Framework quit unexpectedly

Testing started at 4:34 PM ...

```
    Testing started at 4:34 PM ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.cli.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

feature file:

```
 Feature: SomeFeature

Scenario: Verify Data
  Given I receive message
  When System process message
  Then Verify message posted to DB
```

Step Definition file:

```
    public class Test {
    @Given("^I receive message$")
    public void I_receive_message() throws Throwable {
        System.out.print("Given....");
    }

    @When("^System process message$")
    public void System_process_message() throws Throwable {
       System.out.print("When");
    }

    @Then("^Verify message posted to DB$")
    public void Verify_message_posted_to_DB() throws Throwable {
        System.out.print("Then...");
    }
}
```

Please help me with this. already wasted lot of time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is to do with the way you are launching cucumber. Try this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-cli</id>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>-classpath</argument>
          <classpath/>
          <argument>cucumber.api.cli.Main</argument>
          <argument>--strict</argument>
          <argument>--glue</argument>
          <argument>insert.my.mappings.package.here</argument>
          <argument>--plugin</argument>
          <argument>json:${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</argument>
          <argument>--plugin</argument>
          <argument>html:${project.build.directory}/cucumber</argument>
          <argument>--tags</argument>
          <argument>~@ignore</argument>
          <argument>src/main/features/${feature}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```